# Proove that all equivalence relations can be split into equivalence classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is It necessary that all equivalence relations (on any non empty set) can be divided into 2 or more equivalence classes?
If so how will we prove it?

Comment: I don't see why we couldn't have one equivalence class, for example if our equivalence relation was on that integers and was that an integer divides zero.

Comment: $R = X \times X$ is also an equivalence relation on $X$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relation is not trivial, that is, if not for all $x$ and $y$, $x \sim y$, then yes, there are at least two classes to relation. Let $x \not\sim y $, then define $R_x = \{a \, : \, a \sim x \}$ and $R_y=\{a\, :\, a \sim y \}$ are at least two equivalence classes.

Why is there always exist a 'set' of all equivalence classes? I think one should use the Zorn's lemma to prove the existence of the set of all equivalence classes.

Comment: The fact that there is a set of equivalence classes does *not* need any choice. We can just define classes as certain subsets of $X$, so we get a special subset of the power set. All from "non-controversial" axioms. You might be confused with sets of (unique) representatives: these can need choice.

Comment: I can't think of any explicit ways of defining these subsets of $X$ right now, any hints?

Comment: You just did: $R_x = \{y: yRx \}$ is the equivalence class of $x$, as  subset of $X$, and so $\{R_x: x \in X\}$ is also a well-defined set of subsets of $X$ as well. The axiom of replacement is used in the latter.

Comment: I think you are right. Thanks.